# onDestroy() in Android service

Tags: android, android-service

I have 2 questions regarding the onDestroy() method of a service

1.Will the onDestroy() method of a service be called if the service is killed by the system because of lack of memory.

2.Will the onDestroy() method of a service be called if the service is killed because the app that started the service was swiped away by the user in the resent apps screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question.

Based on my previous experience and Android dev docs.`onDestroy()` method of a service is called even if the service is killed by the system.Google Android dev documentation is belowe.

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In
>   such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as
>   either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with
>   the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations
>   hold, the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is
>   effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering
>   receivers) should be complete upon returning from onDestroy().

Second question.

If you would like to kill service when you close your app so yes. Aneroid services are running on the background and normally are not killed when you destroy you're app.

Comment: I do not want my service killed (under any circumstance) till I call the stopService(). Is returning START_REDELIVER_INTENT in the onStartCommand() the only way to do this ?

Comment: If you start services you can define when this service must be stopped. But if device stop service by memory management, you can recall service on onDestroy() method.

Comment: so I just call startService(intent) in the onDestroy() ?

Answer (score 4):

1. When the service is terminated by system onDestroy will be called, but when your application process is terminated onDestroy may not be called.
2. onDestroy() will be called IF service is being terminated as a result. (this is not always the case) See this [discussion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list) for more info.